# How to Automate a Daily SMS Message Detail Report

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio, mobileconnect, sms

How do I automate a daily SMS Message Detail report from Reporting? I want to add logic to a query in order to generate the report daily, export it to the FTP, and then Import it back into a data extension.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the actual issue that you are facing? Please see [ask] and take the [tour] for this site.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a daily SMS report, I would advise not to use the [SMS Message Detail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_re_sms_message_detail_report.htm&type=5) report, but to go straight for the the data from the [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5#mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking) data view:

- The data is much more robust - 41 fields vs 13 in the report
- It's a data view, so you can grab it directly with SQL (no export and import) and apply any transformations you might need at the same time

The only advantage the report has is that it is able to pull data from all child business units at once - with the data view you will need to do run this query in each business unit that you want to extract SMS data from.